# How to call Javascript from @JavascriptInterface method in webView, Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Here is my HTML page codes:

```
<script>
    function native_callback() {
        alert("Test")
    }
</script>
<button onclick='native.appVersion()'>appVersion</button>
```

As you can see, there is only one button, and when I click the button, it will call the @JavascriptInterface method `appVersion()`. What I want to do is to call the javascript function `native_callback()` in the `appVersion()` method. Unfortunately, I will catch a java exception.

And Here is part of my java source codes of WebView class:

```
... // some other codes that not related

getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
addJavascriptInterface(new InJavaScriptLocalObj(), "native");

... // some other codes that not related

final class InJavaScriptLocalObj {
@JavascriptInterface
    public void appVersion() {
        Log.i("JsInterface","Called!")
        loadUrl("javascript:native_callback()");
    }
}
```

And, I can catch the exception from web page :

`Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation -- From line 6 of http://my web page url`

Line 6 is `<button onclick='native.appVersion()'>appVersion</button>`.

BTW, the cods `Log.i("JsInterface","Called!")` has been called, I can see the log.

What should I do ?

**Solution**
Actually, it's must be called in another thread but same as your WebView object.
Here is my codes:

```
web_view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            web_view.loadUrl("javascript:native_callback()");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using handler ?
I checked it works well in my project.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadUrl("javascript:native_callback()");
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's must be another thread, but same thread with webView. And I'm using these: `web_view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                web_view.loadUrl("javascript:native_callback()");
            }
        });`