# Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation

Tags: android, webview

I got an error when js invoke Android

```
Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation
```

,this is the js code:

```
window.SearchActivity.getClickData();
```

,this is the Android code:

```
mAtlasWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new SearchActivity(), "SearchActivity");
@JavascriptInterface
public void getClickData() {
    String mSearchText = mSearchEdit.getText().toString().trim();
    mvpPresenter.getClickData(mSearchText, 1);
}
```

Comment: yes, i set setJavaScriptEnabled(true)，doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289010/how-to-call-javascript-from-javascriptinterface-method-in-webview-android

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the error handler to Java void:

```
public void getClickData() {
    try {
        String mSearchText = mSearchEdit.getText().toString().trim();
        mvpPresenter.getClickData(mSearchText, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot touch views in the interface method. If you need to, you can run on the main thread. Check below code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //add your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the best & fast solution : **surround with try{} in javascript**;